# Trying to predict the length of flight delays using a statistical model

Tags: r, regression

So guys i have a project where i am trying to predict the length of flight delays, in the initial data set i had the variables; Schedule Time of Depature, Actual Time of departure, Distance of flight, Weather, Flight Number, Day of the week flight occurs, Day of the month flight occurs.                                                  now the full model was of the form:

```
    lm(DelayTime ~ schedtime + distance + flightnumber + weather + dayweek + daymonth)
```

[image: Regression Table of Full Model]

the fitted multiple regression model confirms that there is no real evidence that dayweek and daymonth is related to DelayTime but there is overwhelming evidence that schedtime, distance, flightnumber and weather is. the fitted model is û= 25.6108553 + 0.0075735x1 + 0.1677132x2 + 0.0019772x3 + 53.9304840x4 so to reduce Delaytime we should have less severe weather, increase distance of flights etc

I then ran a reduced multiple regression model

[image: Reduced Regression Table]

The model with just schedtime + distance + flightnumber + weather seems adequate, since all terms are highly significant whereas in full model dayweek and daymonth is nowhere near significant

To confirm this I used a partial F test [image: Partial F test to give support reduced model is adequate]

we test H0: β5 = β6 = 0. against H1 :atleast one of β5 and β6  ̸=0. The  p-value being 0.2211 suggests there is not enough evidence against H0 and we conclude that dayweek and daymonth is not related to the DelayTime.

Now I will analyse my reduced model:
[image: Reduced Model table once again]

As we can see the model does not explain the variation in DelayTime well due too a low R^2 Value and it also has a high Residual Error, I was hoping to get some help on how to improve my model by doing some: modelling checking, model selection, transformation of the response. To do this I will include some plots:

[image: Normal QQ plot]

[image: Residuals Vs Fitted plot]

[image]

I tried to add boxcar plots however some of my response variables take negative values so this doesn't work

WE LOVE STATS

Comment: Could you explain how including "flight number" as a *numerical* variable makes any sense?  I'm not saying it doesn't--but this unusual treatment of what would appear to be a *nominal* variable requires explanation.  And please--in order to keep this thread open--please edit your post so that it asks a specific, focused, question.  This site isn't oriented towards just "getting some help."

Comment: Yes of course, I was very confused about how flight number will be related to the overall regression too

Comment: It looks like you have the same issue with `dayofweek` and `dayofmonth` as well.  You're trying to fit a line through them (encoded as integers), but there are some serious issues with that.